# How would you interpret this result of ANOVA and the interaction plot, where the picture seems to contradict the output of ANOVA?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, anova, interaction, model

Let's see the two interaction plots below. It's the same design, just "orthogonally" displayed:

The ANOVA says:

```
> car::Anova(model_chg, type=3)
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: chg
                  Pr(>F)   
(Intercept)       0.011894 * 
AB                0.983652   
XY                0.001262 **
AB:XY             0.123200
```

which means, that there is the main effect of XY (the effect at all levels of AB) and no interaction.

But the picture says, that there exists an interaction, quite visible, and it's dis-ordinal (crossing) one, so the main effect can be hardly found. Instead, we can see a partial effect, a simple effect between X and Y of the variable XY at the level of B of variable AB.

In other words: ANOVA says: no interaction, main effect of XY, picture says: interaction exists, no main effects, simple effect of XY at B exists.

When I did an analysis of contrasts (X vs Y at A and at B), it confirmed this finding: no effect except X vs. Y at B.

How can I interpret that little "discrepancy" between the ANOVA and the picture?

[image]

EDIT:
the data:

```
data <- structure(list(chg = c(0.2, 0.4, -0.0999999999999996, 0.9, 0, 
0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.3, 1.3, -0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 2.1, 
0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0, -0.1, 0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, -0.2, 0, 
0, 0.5, 0.1, -0.2, 0.2, 3, 0.3, 0, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, -0.1, 0.3, 
-0.1, -0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, -0.0999999999999996, 0, -0.3, 
0.3, 0.2, 0.9, -0.1, 0.9, -0.1, -0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0, -0.5, 
0.5, -0.3, 0, 0.1, -0.8, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 1.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.399999999999999, 
2.4, 0.3, 0, -0.2, 0.2, 1.1, 0.5, 0.1, -0.21, -0.3, 0.0399999999999996, 
0.6, 0.0499999999999998, 0.31, 0.47, 0.0499999999999998, 0.52, 
-0.12, 0.0499999999999998, 0.13, 0.35, 0.15, 0.44, -0.66, 1.18, 
0.69, 0.4, 0.38, 0.63, 0.96, 0.26, 0.12, 0.13, 0.24, -0.0799999999999996, 
-0.0699999999999998, 0.27, 0.2, 0.33, 0.0600000000000001, 0.0499999999999998, 
0.32, 0.18, 0.38, 0.12, 0.62, 0.47, 0.33, -0.81, 1.31, 0.42, 
-0.0800000000000001, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0, 0.4, -0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.5, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0, -0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.8, 0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.4, 
0.3, 1.1, 1.6, -0.2, 0.4, 0.3, -0.3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1
), XY = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
"B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A"), AB = c("X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Y"), Baseline = c(-3.1, -3.5, 
-2.7, -2.7, -3.5, -3.1, -2.6, -4.1, -3.3, -3.5, -2.7, -2.9, -3.4, 
-3.2, -2.9, -4, -3.7, -1.4, -3.7, -3.6, -3.2, -2.5, -2.7, -2.7, 
-3.3, -1.5, -2.8, -3.4, -3.8, -2.8, -2.7, -3.3, -3, -3, -2.8, 
-2.2, -2.5, -2.5, -3.9, -3.8, -2.5, -2.8, -2.4, -3.1, -2.8, -2, 
-2.6, -2.3, -3.3, -1.4, -2.7, -2.3, -3.3, -2.6, -3.9, -4, -2, 
-3.1, -1.9, -2.4, -1.8, -3.3, -2.3, -4.1, -3.4, -3.2, -2.7, -3.1, 
-3.9, -2.8, -4.5, -4, -2.6, -2.7, -4, -3.5, -4.1, -3.2, -4.3, 
-4.2, -4.5, -3.9, -2.9, -3.7, -4, -3.24, -2.48, -2.51, -5.08, 
-3.09, -3.29, -2.37, -3, -2.54, -2.67, -3.46, -3.28, -2.64, -3.81, 
-3.17, -2.71, -2.98, -3.49, -2.56, -2.92, -2.63, -3.56, -3.78, 
-2.56, -1.97, -3.61, -2.18, -2.75, -2.14, -3.31, -2.41, -2.71, 
-3.15, -2.1, -2.86, -0.99, -3.57, -1.22, -3.08, -2.35, -2.4, 
-4.6, -2.56, -2.65, -4.3, -2.7, -2.7, -2.5, -3.5, -2.5, -3.1, 
-2.7, -3.2, -2.6, -2.9, -2.9, -2.9, -2.4, -3.1, -3.1, -2.8, -3, 
-2.2, -2.8, -3.1, -1.8, -3.4, -2, -3.1, -2.9, -2.6, -3.3, -2.8, 
-2.7, -2.5, -2.7, -2.7, -3, -2.6, -2.9)), row.names = c(NA, -165L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Model:

```
> library(emmeans)
> options(contrasts=c('contr.sum','contr.poly'))
> model_chg <- lm(chg ~ XY * AB + Baseline, data = data)
> car::Anova(model_chg, type=3)
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: chg
            Sum Sq  Df F value   Pr(>F)   
(Intercept)  1.471   1  6.4739 0.011894 * 
XY           2.449   1 10.7778 0.001262 **
AB           0.000   1  0.0004 0.983652   
Baseline     0.198   1  0.8694 0.352519   
XY:AB        0.546   1  2.4014 0.123200   
Residuals   36.357 160                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> car::Anova(model_chg, type=2)
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: chg
          Sum Sq  Df F value  Pr(>F)   
XY         1.906   1  8.3862 0.00431 **
AB         0.003   1  0.0123 0.91167   
Baseline   0.198   1  0.8694 0.35252   
XY:AB      0.546   1  2.4014 0.12320   
Residuals 36.357 160                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> joint_tests(model_chg)
 model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 XY           1 160  10.778 0.0013 
 AB           1 160   0.000 0.9837 
 XY:AB        1 160   2.401 0.1232 

em_chg <- emmeans(object = model_chg, specs = ~XY * AB, mode = "df.error", data=data, adjust="mvt")

# Adjusted for multiplicity
> contrast(em_chg, 
+          list(X_AB = c(1, 0, -1, 0), 
+               Y_AB = c(0, 1, 0, -1), 
+               A_XY = c(1, -1, 0, 0),
+               B_XY = c(0, 0, 1, -1)
+          ), adjust = "mvt")
 contrast estimate    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 X_AB        0.133 0.122 160   -0.170   0.4361  1.090  0.6383 
 Y_AB       -0.130 0.112 160   -0.408   0.1482 -1.156  0.5937 
 A_XY       -0.150 0.090 160   -0.373   0.0723 -1.672  0.2830 
 B_XY       -0.414 0.145 160   -0.773  -0.0543 -2.849  0.0183 

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: mvt method for 4 estimates 
P value adjustment: mvt method for 4 tests 

# Unadjusted (nominal)
> contrast(em_chg, 
+          list(X_AB = c(1, 0, -1, 0), 
+               Y_AB = c(0, 1, 0, -1), 
+               A_XY = c(1, -1, 0, 0),
+               B_XY = c(0, 0, 1, -1)
+          ), adjust = "none")
 contrast estimate    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 X_AB        0.133 0.122 160   -0.108   0.3750  1.090  0.2775 
 Y_AB       -0.130 0.112 160   -0.352   0.0920 -1.156  0.2493 
 A_XY       -0.150 0.090 160   -0.328   0.0273 -1.672  0.0966 
 B_XY       -0.414 0.145 160   -0.701  -0.1269 -2.849  0.0050 

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the lines on the first plot cross is not in and of itself proof of an interaction at significance 0.05 (or any significance level). A p-value of 0.12 might be said to suggest that there is "probably" some type of interaction, which we can eye-ball from plot one. But is it for *sure* an interaction? No.

Same thing on plot 2. Is the fact that one slope is positive and one is negative in and of itself proof of an interaction. No. This is, in fact, a good example of why statistics exist. Our visual intuitions fail us and suggest to us a pattern when really there is not sufficient evidence to distinguish the pattern from random noise.

Comment: Yes, but then how it's possible, that the ANOVA reports the main effect, while the contrast analysis (either the dummy Tukey HSD for all pairs, or the specific subset if contrasts I provide to the program) shows *only* the one simple effect (at p<0.001), which immediately points to the interaction? Can it be that the contrast analysis supports the graph, while the overall ANOVA is fooled by something? I mention this contrast analysis in my post. Moreover, the graph doesn't support the claim that the main effect even exists. That drove me to ask this question: more contradicting results.

Comment: In other words - how is that possible, that a single simple effect confirmed by the contrast analysis (adjusted for multiplicity using the multivariate t distribution) agrees with the picture, is able to "force" the ANOVA to report the whole main effect (at both levels of the second variable - by the definition of the main effect) and invalidates the interaction at the same time. This is something that I wanted to consult.

Comment: Can you edit the post to include actual numerical results for your contrast analysis? Just looking at graphs isn't really useful.

Comment: I added the data and the calculations I made. I use type 3 (or 2 for no interaction) ANOVA-like analysis - a sequence of the likelihood ratio tests to assess the main and interaction effects. I analyse change from baseline (in my industry it's the only allowed method for non-randomized trials) adjusted for the baseline (it's required by the industry). If you omit the baseline, results are slightly different, but the overall outcome (in terms of significance) is exactly the same.

Comment: So, as we can see, the LR test over lm() (pretty equivalent to the type 3 ANOVA) finds the main effect and no interaction (which by definition means, that XY must differ on both levels of AB, A and B). But the analysis of contrasts finds only the partial (simple) effect. And the graph seems to reflect the analysis of contrasts. I reported also the unadjusted analysis - it doesn't change much, the results are consistent.

Comment: There is too much black-and-white reasoning in this discussion. You do not have proof that there is no interaction, you only have insufficient data to prove an interaction exists. Absence of proof is not the same as proof of absence. I think the P value for interaction is low enough here that I'd consider doing comparisons of simple effects.